# Myanmar font set up at website

Tags: unicode, fonts, webfonts

My website needs to allow users to key-in Myanmar font.
I am looking around and there is no proper documentation how to setup at webpage.

A few font providers are found like [thanlwin](http://my.duniakitab.com/ThanLwinSoft/ThanLwinSoft/), [MyMyanmar Language](http://www.mymyanmar.net/) ,etc. But there is no proper documentation how to setup their libraries.

I saw a few Myanmar unicode fonts, don't know which one to choose.

May I have some guide how to install lib at my server to support Myanmar font at my webpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia uses the fallback sans serif (Helvetica / Arial) of your operating system for displaying *Myanmar*.

if you would prefer a specific font you can convert it the common font files (of course with the permission of the font designer):
https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Now you can upload it to your server and include it via `@font-face` (you’ll receive an example css file).

Comment: any news on this?